# SQL Server - Select

Tags: sql, select

Please, how do I SELECT, to get the result column?

[columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3wCZ.jpg)

Comment: Ask again after reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Include all relevant information in your question. Do not require folks to reference information at external sites.

Comment: Please, I am sorry. Next time I will do right. And thanks for the advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT machine, software
FROM ms_tbl
INNER JOIN machine_tbl
    ON machine_tbl.machine_id = ms_tbl.machine_id
INNER JOIN software_tbl
    ON software_tbl.software_id = ms_tbl.software_id;
```